# NSUserDefault work only one time in Keyboard Extension in iOS8

Tags: nsuserdefaults, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have a options that let user choose background color of `Keyboard` with Keyboard extension with XCode beta 1.

I can save and load from `NSUserDefault`. But Only one time. after i changed value twice and test with `UITextField` (Even iOS Built in App). It doesn't work and not change background color.

However when i quit app and reopen , that changed value is working and background color is changing.

Here is my code that save data to `NSUserDefault`.

```
self.defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.mycompany.keyboard"];

- (void)savePreferences
{
    [self.defaults setBool:self.redColorSwitch.on forKey:@"redColor"];

    [self.defaults synchronize];
}
```

and load code is

```
self.defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.mycompany.keyboard"];

if([self.defaults boolForKey:@"redColor"])
    {
        self.myKeyboard.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else
    {
        self.myKeyboard.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Is there any wrong in my codes?